# A few Questions about implementing a render loop in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, gdi+, game-engine, message-queue

**Guten Tag zusammen!** (German: *Good Day everyone!*)

Please excuse my English, it is not my mother tongue. Since I have already found a lot of good answers to my questions here I would like now to ask you some.

In the last few days I have done a little research to the question *"What is the best way to implement a game loop in Windows Forms?"*. And I have found a good explained solution form the [SlimDX team](http://slimdx.org/tutorials/BasicWindow.php), which it is based on the work of [Tom Miller](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmiller/archive/2005/05/05/415008.aspx).

My Questions are:

**First:** We I use this solution for an game loop which is the best way to redraw the From after I have rendered a frame? A way I have often found is to call *Invalidete()*, but this does not look like a good idea to me. Wouldn't this add a message to the message queue and break the while-loop every frame?

**Second:** To my understanding this loop will consume an entire CPU-Thread (Core). Is there and good way to slow it down to a recommended frame rate that does not consume an entire CPU-Thread?

**Third:** Is GDI+ capable of render a simply 2D game?. When did Drawing becomes so complex that it is advisable to use a hardware accelerated drawing whit some DirectX or OpenGL wrappers?

Comment: These are three different technical issues, but the SO format only permits one per question.  So, you might do better yp edit out your second and third points and post them as separate questions.

Comment: You break all the rules in game code.  Don't use Invalidate(), use CreateGraphics() to directly draw to the screen.  Burning core is okay, normally paced by the vertical refresh but that's hard to come by in non-DirectX code.  System.Drawing is okay for 2D games, be sure to cache bitmaps and pay attention to the pixel format (32bppPArgb is 10x faster), GPU rendering requires drastically different code.

Comment: Why not just use XNA and not worry about all these things? Microsoft has stopped supporting it, but it's still a viable option. And certainly it's going to be way more efficient (for games in particular) than GDI.

Answer (score 1):

> A way I have often found is to call `Invalidate()`, but this does not look like a good idea to me. Wouldn't this add a message to the message queue and break the while-loop every frame?

Yes, that's a bad idea. You don't control the frequency at which the messages are delivered to your window, which means you shouldn't rely on it.

> To my understanding this loop will consume an entire CPU-Thread (Core). Is there and good way to slow it down to a recommended frame rate that does not consume an entire CPU-Thread?

You can use the [`SpinWait` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait.aspx) (**NOT** [`Thread.SpinWait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx)) to wait short amount of times. Base the waiting time on the duration of the curret frame and the desired framerate.

But usually the game loop taking an entire core isn't a problem. It may even be desired if you want to maximize your framerate.

> Is GDI+ capable of render a simply 2D game?

Yes, although it'd be a really simple game. GDI is *slow*. I advise you to go with a hardware-accelerated solution right from the start, that way you won't have to rewrite everything if GDI proves to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.When i should not use Invalidate() to repaint the Form. How should i do it?

Comment: The linked SlimDX article explains it really well, I wouldn't explain it better.

Comment: "Wouldn't this add a message to the message queue and break the while-loop every frame?" The correct answer to this question is _no_. Window invalidation is not handled like other window messages; invalidating part of a window simply marks the window, and then Windows synthesizes a WM_PAINT message when the program fetches the next message. No WM_PAINT message actually winds up in the message queue. That said, WM_PAINT is returned only when there are no other messages left to process, so isn't ideal for high-frame-rate games. But it won't fill up the message queue.